# Override Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection

Tags: magento

I'm trying to override this class in order to change the behavior of the function

`_applyProductLimitations`

and add another new function (so i can filter by two or more categories)

Anyone can help telling me how to override it in order that all the product collection can call my new function without getting the error that it's not defined in

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to the `config.xml` file of your module under the `<global>` tag

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <product_collection>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
</models>
```

Then create the file `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php` with the following content.

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection {
    protected function _applyProductLimitations(){
        //your magic here
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you :D you saved my day
i had some wrong things in the config.xml rewrite